# iPhone Function, Swap Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function

Hi I want to put this into a function.

```
NSMutableArray* weekArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [weekArray addObject:@"Before School"];
    [weekArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    [weekArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    [weekArray addObject:@"Break"];
    [weekArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    [weekArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    [weekArray addObject:@"Lunch"];
    [weekArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    [weekArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    [weekArray addObject:@"After School"];
    return weekArray;
```

I want to be able to call it and when called, replace weekArray with the array I choose. Possible?

Comment: Can you rephrase/clarify what you're asking?

Comment: This isn't a question, and it seems to me is no different from a previous question you posted that's already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677488/compress-this-into-a-function

Comment: @jlehr: here OP wants to use a single array as a parameter instead of six objects as parameters.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, the previous question and answers were ever so helpful, only after a change in plans, Im don't understand how to do the above without the need to ask.

Comment: Im merely asking a question, someone is rating me down, why is this necessary? It is a different question, if you don't understand ask like Kubi. Thank you for your answer previously jlehr, and I am sorry I didnt know of it as I had already had it working with a previous answer. BoltClock is right, thats what I intend, any ideas how? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're asking, sure. Here's an example:

```
NSArray *arrayLikeThat() {
    return [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Before School",
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
                                             @"Break",
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
                                             @"Lunch",
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
                                             @"After School",
                                             nil];
}
```

You can assign the result to any variable you want.